# GAE sql (GQL) correct format?

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

My sql looks like this :

SELECT * FROM Contact_Info_Entry where Name.length < 18

[ Got incorrect GQL syntax error message ]

"Name" is a String in the Contact_Info_Entry.java class, I'm not familiar with sql, let alone GQL, if I want to select all names less than 18 characters long, what's the correct GQL syntax to use ?

Comment: Also your query should contain the "Column name in query" not name of some java variable. that "Name" is a java variable but not a column name in table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't filter by a field's length with GQL.

However, you could achieve this if you denormalize your model and include the length of `Name` as a field in your model.

Answer (score 0):

GQL does not provide any function like `length`.

In your app engine application, you have to find length of name and make one field named length.

Then, you can fire a query directly on the length column.