# How do I write a gql query that filters on the length of a field?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to filter a query by the length of one of the fields in a datastore but it appears I cannot include a len function in the WHERE clause.

```
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT CommentCode FROM Comments " + 
                "WHERE RefObjType = 'paper' AND RefObjID = :1 AND len(CommentCode) = :2" +
                "ORDER BY CommentCode DESC ", RefObjID, 1)
```

This results in: `BadQueryError: Parse Error: Invalid WHERE Condition at symbol (`

Can anyone give me an example of how I might get this to work?

The RefObjID part works because the entire query works if I just leave out the len() filter.

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986688/gae-sql-gql-correct-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:
Modify the query to retrieve the results in DESC order and then process the results by accessing the required result after the query retrieval.

Change query:

```
  q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT CommentCode FROM Comments " + 
                    "WHERE RefObjType = 'paper' AND RefObjID = :1" +
                    "ORDER BY CommentCode DESC ", RefObjID, 1)
```

After this select the rows that have `length(CommentCode)==2` with a loop and a conditional statement.

Comment: Thanks.  This pointed me in the direction of finding an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (at least as far I understand it) because of how the DataStore works. The length of the string needs to be a property (either static or dynamic using `db.Expando`) of your `Model`, and then you filter on that.